# IllegalArgumentException in Retrofit / must not have replace block

Tags: android, retrofit

I have the following code :

```
    @GET("api.php?company_name={name}")
    Call<Model> getRoms_center(@Query("name") String name);
```

According to the official docs, I must use @Query, and i'm using it, but i'm getting the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "company_name={name}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You should do it like that instead:

```
@GET("api.php")
Call<Model> getRoms_center(@Query("company_name") String name);
```

Answer (score 40):

Example URL is: `http://service.com/movies/list?movie_lang=hindi`

for that URL you can use this:

```
@GET("http://service.com/movies/list")
Single<JsonElement> getMovieList(@Query("movie_lang") String userLanguage);
```

Answer (score 3):

Example Url: https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.jsonlatitude=31.3952348&longitude=&elevation=2000&timeformat=1

to pass in retrofit for that URL you can use this:

```
@GET("today.json")
Call<SalahMainResponse> getSalahTiming(
    @Query("latitude") double latitude,
    @Query("longitude") double longitude,
    @Query("elevation") int elevation,
    @Query("timeformat") int timeformat
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin You should do it like that instead:

Example URL: https://codeforces.com/api/user.info?handles=maity_amit_2003

to pass Retrofit in Kotlin:

```
interface CodeForcesAPIService {
   @GET("api/user.info?")
   fun getApiResponse(@Query("handles") uid:String): Call<CodeForcesModel>
 }
```