# Rest Api using Retrofit in Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

My code

```
public interface ApiInterface 

{

    @GET("convert?q=USD_{currency}&compact=ultra&apiKey="+API_KEY)
    Call<Currency> getRates(@Path("currency") String currency );
}
```

But I am getting the following Error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "q=USD_{currency}&compact=ultra&apiKey=9b1166408fb8799dee9e" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.`

Comment: Use Query instead of Path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException in Retrofit / must not have replace block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964147/illegalargumentexception-in-retrofit-must-not-have-replace-block)

Answer (score 1):

make your interface like this:

```
@GET("convert")
Call<Currency> getRates(@Query("q") String query, @Query("compact") String compact, @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);
```

You can call it like this way:

```
String mCurrency="$";

Call<Currency> call = mApiInterface.getRates("USD_"+mCurrency, "ultra", API_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your query parameters inside of the interface like this:

```
@GET("convert")
Call<Currency> getRates(@Query("q") String currency, @Query("compact") String compact, @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);
```