# How to setup the static end of the url in retrofit call

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I got a retrofit api interface but how to set it up properly according parameters

```
@GET("/users/profile/{User}?age={Age}&amp;api_key=randomkey")
suspend fun enableVoice(
        @Path("User") user: String?,
        @Query("age") age: String?
): Response<UserResponse?>
```

I got this error and not sure how to setup api side properly

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "age={Age}&amp;api_key=randomkey" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

Please let me know how to make it run

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35964169/2199001), I think you'll need to do something like this :

```
@GET("/users/profile/{User}")
suspend fun enableVoice(
        @Path("User") user: String?,
        @Query("age") age: String?,
        @Query("api_key") key: String?,
): Response<UserResponse?>
```

It's also possible to use `@QueryMap`, where you would supply a map of key value pairs.

```
@GET("/users/profile/{User}")
suspend fun enableVoice(
        @Path("User") user: String?,
        @QueryMap queryParams: Map<String, String>
): Response<UserResponse?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly add the query part in the URL. Passing it in the method with @Query annotation will automatically add it in the final URL being requested. So your request should be

```
@GET("/users/profile/{User}")
  suspend fun enableVoice(
    @Path("User") user: String?,
    @Query("age") age: String?,
    @Query("api_key") key: String?
  ): Response<UserResponse?>
```